# i change the "class" attribute of a node that exist in SVG, but not applied ! why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, d3.js

i change the "class" attribute of a node that exist in SVG, but not applied !

this is my Code (in my Directive angularJs):

```
  node = node.data(force.nodes(),function (d) { return d.id; });
  var newNode = node.enter()
         .append("g")
         .attr("display",function(d) {return d.dis })
         .attr("class",function(d){
                return  "node " + d.class;
         })
```

why?

TNX

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. You're appending a new element and setting its class. Are you saying that the class is not set?

Comment: it's not my means. my problem is: i draw a graph with D3, and any "g" has "class". but when i change the "class" attribute of nodes(force.nodes()) and redraw graph, the new "class" not applied to "g". why? @LarsKotthoff

Comment: Could you post the code you're using to do that?

Comment: thnx Lars. this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MoHSenMHS/4GJ3v/) show my problem, I draw my graph, and after 2 sec. i change the "name" of last node, and restart my graph. but "name" not change?!!! @LarsKotthoff

Comment: It looks like you're only updating the data. This will not update the DOM elements automatically.

Comment: uhum. how update the DOM elements? thnx @LarsKotthoff

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are changing the `"class"` attribute of a `"g"` inside the node, and not the class of the node itself. To change the class of the node you can simply do:

```
var newNode = node.attr("class",function (d) { return  "node " + d.class; })
```

Comment: It looks to me like `node` is a selection of `g` elements. In any case, OP is changing the class of a newly appended element.

Comment: it's not my means. my problem is: i draw a graph with D3, and any "g" has "class". but when i change the "class" attribute of nodes(force.nodes()) and redraw graph, the new "class" not applied to "g". why? @tomtomtom